# Cannot create notebook immediately after creating group (modern group not

Tags: onenote, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

With Microsoft Graph I would like to create a **Group** and then after that create a **Notebook** (onenote) in that group directory.

First I execute a HTTP call to :

> POST /groups

with the required access token in the header and JSON object of the Group in the body. (http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_groups).
If successful it will return a JSON object with the complete property of the group.

So far there was no problem, I've managed to get the {ID} (in GUID) of the group which will be required to create a notebook. Let's say for this example the {ID} of my Group is 123456789-abcd-4321-bbbb-9876543210aaa

Next for the notebook I execute a HTTP call to :

> POST /groups/{ID}/notes/notebooks

And then I got following JSON response :

```
"error": {
"code": "20160",
"message": "No modern group was found that matches the ID 123456789-abcd-4321-bbbb-9876543210aaa",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "85b85297-ad3b-424d-b18f-2b1da904f5fc",
  "date": "2016-01-29T08:19:27"
}
```

I've tried so many things to get a workaround for this issue. One time I set a break point between the method to create group and the method to create notebook in my program. I ran my program until the point it has finished creating the group. Then I stop, and try to open notebook tab from Office365 website in the browser and I found this :

[image]

In English it means "We are creating your notebook. It may take a few minutes. We will finish this even if you close the browser". I took about 10 seconds before I was redirected to OneNote Online page (the url is my sharepoint tenant name).

After that I continue my program and suddenly it successfully created the notebook.

I need some help here! I need to create the notebook immediately after creating the group without having to open up a browser. I think it has something to do with sharepoint sites creation for the Group.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating groups does take some time (usually ~ 5 minutes). 
It is recommended that you first query to see if group has been created or not and then create the notebook.

you can query drive endpoint to find if group has been provisioned.
GET /beta/groups/{id}/drive